# Запись структуры в текстовый файл Си

Tags: c

Необходимо записать структуру в текстовый файл (чтобы его можно было просмотреть в любом текстовом редакторе)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

struct person
{
    char name[16];
    int age;
};

int save(char * filename, struct person *p);

int main(void)
{
    char * filename = "person.txt";
    struct person tom = { "Tom", 21 };

    save(filename, &tom);
    getch();
    return 0;
}

// запись структуры в файл
int save(char * filename, struct person *p)
{
    FILE * fp;
    char *c;
    int size = sizeof(struct person); // количество записываемых байтов

    if ((fp = fopen(filename, "w")) == NULL)
    {
    perror("Error occured while opening file");
    return 1;
    }
    // устанавливаем указатель на начало структуры
    c = (char *)p;
    // посимвольно записываем в файл структуру
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
    putc(*c++, fp);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Однако в таком случае получаем такое содержимое файла
Tom                . Получается что цифры некорректно читаются редактором. Помогите с проблемой. Спасибо.

Comment: Вы тпо сути выполняете запись в бинарном режиме. Хотите в текстовом - пишите что-то типа `fprintf(fp,"%s %d",tom.name,tom.age);`

Comment: В таком случае, name бы тоже заполнялся в бинарном режиме и тоже отображался неверно...а у меня конкретно проблемы с заполнением файла цифрами

Comment: @АндрейСавчук, текстовые данные обычно одинаково выглядят при записи в текстовом и бинарном режиме (если вы конечно не в utf-16 в файл записывает).